# How can I measure the length of an asyncio event loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have an application which is calling `loop.run_forever()` after scheduling some tasks. Those tasks will connect to web services and then schedule new tasks on the loop based on input from those services.

I want to find a way of keeping track of the loop to check whether there are tasks being created which are never completing. Ideally I would measure the number of tasks in the loop periodically and write it to a file, or make it available via an http call.

Comment: You can try to keep the data in database and monitor/poll instances of tasks. I would be happy to find a 'native' python way to do it.

Comment: That's a good thought but there is other code within dependencies in my application which are putting tasks on the loop too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collect all tasks, then count them, compute some other metric of "loop length" or perform inspection.

```
asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop=loop)
```

Answer (score 3):

In python 3.10, you can get the number of tasks in the current thread like that :

```
len(asyncio.all_tasks(asyncio.get_running_loop()))
```

Comment: I think this works since 3.7